# Why the name "realm" and "principal" in Java EE security?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee

Why are the name "realm" chosen for something that seems like (at least for me) to be a group of security constraints and the users allowed to access. I may be wrong. If I translate it to my mother tongue I get that it is a "kingdom, territory". I don't understand it.

> Principal: An entity that can be authenticated by an authentication
>   protocol in a security service that is deployed in an enterprise. A
>   principal is identified by using a principal name and authenticated by
>   using authentication data.

And principal, which make no sense what so ever in my mother tounge is even harder. Could someone explain?

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html

Comment: Not to get off topic here, but does calling an object-oriented language and runtime environment Java not bother you? At least with realms and principals I can see the analogy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The word "realm" is used here as a spatial analogy for a set -- things can be inside a set or not inside, same as a kingdom.  A security "realm" is a set such that all things in that set are affected by the same rules, but that things from outside that region are treated as foreign, suspicious, or otherwise have less than full access to things inside that realm.

To understand how this might work, consider a Medieval castle.  The people inside the castle are assumed to be more loyal to the king than the people outside, so security focuses on keeping the enemies outside from getting in.  Within the castle, there is a keep where only the most trusted are allowed, and security mechanisms (guards and gates) limit access to the keep from the rest of the castle.

---

You might see terms like "security domains" and "trust domains" in the security literature.  These are other ways of saying "realm".

---

A "principal" is that to which authority can be granted or denied.  It can be a user, a role, a machine, etc.  It is the "principal" (first or foremost) entity in the authority matrix.

"Principal" is (IIRC) related to the word "prince" and is used in the sense of something that can exercise significant but not unlimited authority.

The definition quoted in the OP muddles "authentication" and "authorization" which is a common mistake.  Just think about Princes exercising power within limitations which requires *authorization*.  In Java-EE in particular, principals are involved in [IBAC](http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/ibac.html) (or a related scheme like RBAC) but the term is used more broadly in the security literature in a way that is independent of whether authentication happens but not of whether authorization happens.

---

One possible source of confusion: you might think a *prince* should rule a *principality*, but the analogy breaks down here.  In feudal Europe, maybe there was a 1:1 relationship between princes and principalities (a kind of *realm*), but there is no 1:1 relationship between principals and realms.  A given realm is not necessarily ruled by any particular principal.

Comment: I think I got the first part about the realm, but the principal I am not sure. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Also: [principal -- a person who takes a leading part in any activity](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/principal).

Comment: @Bruno, quite right.  Please consider "leading an activity" is equivalent to "exercise of authority" in my answer.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Okey, I see. Thanks. So instead of using the "Principal to prince" mapping we could say that it is the king, the king of the realm? And it is this who determines whether or not you are granted access to the realm?

Comment: @user626912, no there is no "king of the realm".  Each realm has many princes and groups of princes.  Then authority to perform an action, e.g. to enter a castle, is granted to prince P of realm R and group G of realm S, but not to prince Q of realm S.

Comment: @user626912, a principal is simply someone that the realm knows about ("can be authenticated").  They may have certain rights.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Oh, so the user trying to log in is the actual principal..at least represented by that entity?

Comment: Actually, in Java, there is also a distinction between Principal and [Subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/Subject.html) (which "*represents a grouping of related information for a single entity, such as a person*"). "*Each identity is represented as a Principal within the Subject*". (Sorry to add a bit more confusion, it's just the way it works in Java.) You could see this as someone being able to produce multiple IDs (e.g. a passport, a driving licence and a member's card of the local sports club).

Comment: @Bruno, so a `Principal` encapsulates the portion of the data relevant to authorization but the `Subject` contains other information as well?

Comment: @MikeSamuel, yes. For example, a servlet request will be associated with a single `Subject`, which may have an `X500Principal` (coming from a client cert), but can also add role principals along the way (often part of, or straight after, authentication), so as to let the authorization components make a decision based on which principals the subject holds. Other example, as the [JAAS guide says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html#Subject): "*a person may have a name Principal ("John Doe") and a SSN Principal ("123-45-6789")*".